# Unable to deploy java chain code which is provided by IBM Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

Request from restclient:

POST  http://localhost:7050/chaincode

Request:
    {
      "jsonrpc": "2.0",
      "method": "deploy",
      "params": {
        "type": 1,
        "chaincodeID":{
            "name": "raja"
        },
        "ctorMsg": {
            "args":["init", "a", "100", "b", "200"]
        }
      },
      "id": 5
    }

Register java chain code with chaincode id name:

```
rajasekhar@rajasekhar-VirtualBox:~/mychaincode/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/java/chaincode_example02/build/distributions/chaincode_example02/bin$ CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=raja  ./chaincode_example02
Jun 13, 2017 1:24:06 PM org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeBase newPeerClientConnection
INFO: Configuring channel connection to peer.
Jun 13, 2017 1:24:09 PM org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeBase chatWithPeer
INFO: Connecting to peer.
Jun 13, 2017 1:24:09 PM io.grpc.internal.TransportSet$1 call
INFO: Created transport io.grpc.netty.NettyClientTransport@599c4539(/127.0.0.1:7051) for /127.0.0.1:7051
Jun 13, 2017 1:24:10 PM io.grpc.internal.TransportSet$TransportListener transportReady
INFO: Transport io.grpc.netty.NettyClientTransport@599c4539(/127.0.0.1:7051) for /127.0.0.1:7051 is ready
Jun 13, 2017 1:24:10 PM org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeBase chatWithPeer
INFO: Registering as 'raja' ... sending REGISTER
java.lang.RuntimeException: [raja]Chaincode handler org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.fsm cannot handle message (INIT) with payload size (23) while in state: established
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.Handler.handleMessage(Handler.java:493)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeBase$1.onNext(ChaincodeBase.java:188)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeBase$1.onNext(ChaincodeBase.java:181)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onMessage(ClientCalls.java:305)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$2.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:423)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:54)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor$TaskRunner.run(SerializingExecutor.java:154)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Please give more information about what you're trying to do. You got the chaincode from somewhere or you wrote it?

Comment: Maybe have a look at this: https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/issues/905

Answer (score 0):

you will need to provide more information as to what you have done so far. With just the error message - its not possible to pin point the cause of failure.

Here is excellent documentation available on how to write a Java Chain Code for Blockchain: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-chaincode-for-java-developers/index.html

I am hoping you have seen the above documentation. Do go through the steps one by one. The documentation is extensive in terms of setting your environment to writing your first chain code in Java.

Hope this helps.